# Calling generic methods from injected classes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

In my .NET 6.0 application I have a controller that in many places call a generic method from an injected class. The code is currently schematically structured as follows:

```
InjectedClass.Method<ClassA>(List<ClassA>);
InjectedClass.Method<ClassB>(List<ClassB>);
```

This pattern repeats in many places throughout the controller. I would like to define at the top of the controller an array-like object of the classes used and then call the methods automatically something like:

```
classesToUse = [ClassA, ClassB];

foreach (class in classesToUse)
{
  InjectedClass.Method<class>(List<class>)
}
```

Is there a way to achieve something like this? I have tried many thigs using typeof() and nameof() etc.. but it never quite worked.

Comment: Is there a relationship between the classes, by that I mean do they inherit or extend a shared class? If so you could use that as the type for your generic.

Comment: You could do that using an interface that is defined in all of your injected classes, or using reflection to get the method by name.

Comment: Shouldn't the parameter be an instance? such as `new List<ClassA>{...}`

Comment: Add more information. Which type has `InjectedClass` in controller?  It is interface?

Comment: injected class = instance?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but I think that I've encountered your problem before. Based on the limited information you gave I think you could use the strategy pattern. Don't forget to register the context and strategies in your DI container. You can use the following code as reference and modify it to your situation.

```
public class InsertSomeGoodNameContext : IInsertSomeGoodNameContext
{

    private readonly IEnumerable<ISomeStrategyStrategy> _strategies;

    public InsertSomeGoodNameContext (IEnumerable<ISomeStrategyStrategy> strategies)
    {
        _strategies = strategies;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Execute(string someParam, string someType)
    {
        var strategy = DetermineStrategy(someType);

        if (strategy == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        };

        return strategy.Execute(someParam);
    }

    private ISomeStrategyStrategy? DetermineStrategy(string someType)
    {
        return _strategies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SupportedTypes.Contains(someType));
    }
}
```

And then implement strategies as follows:

```
public interface ISomeStrategyStrategy
{
    IEnumerable<string> Execute(string someParam);

    IEnumerable<string> SupportedTypes { get; }
}

public class Strategy1 : ISomeStrategyStrategy
{
    public IEnumerable<string> SupportedTypes => new[] { "Example" };

    public IEnumerable<string> Execute(string someParam)
    {
        return new List<string>() { someParam, someParam };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you should have some instance. And you are foreaching these instance instead of foreaching the "Types".

The injectclass.

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public void Print<T>(List<T> value)
        {
            foreach (var item in value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);   //Simple print
            }
        }
    }
```

Just regard `int` and `string` as class1 and class2 here.

```
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly TestClass _testClass;

        public ValuesController(TestClass testClass)
        {
            this._testClass = testClass;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public void test()
        {           
            //You should have these instance for parameter
            var a=new List<int> {1,2,3};
            var b= new List<string> { "A1", "B1", "C1" };
 
            var objects = new object[] { a, b };

            foreach (var o in objects)
            {
                dynamic item = o;
                _testClass.Print(item); 
            }

        }
```

Output
[image]